# How to create an option to choose multiple articles in joomla plugin configuration?

Tags: joomla

I'm creating a Joomla plugin that allows user to choose multiple articles in plugin configuration.
In the plugin, I want to collect the id of these articles.
Can anyone help me or give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not default functionality for artcle list .
you can list article catagory like:-

```
<field name="catids" type="category" extension="com_content" multiple="true" size="10" default="all" label="Categories" description="Select categories" />
```

For article list you need to create custom form field:-
create an folder named elements and add file with field name what you give name in xml for field
For step by step doc follow [Jdoc](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type) 
or download  plugin for help and get code for creating k2 catogries in plugin may be this helpful for you [sp share](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-share/social-multi-share/18742).